# How to fix Upload image to twitter with Selenium (Python)

Tags: python, image, selenium, twitter

Currently i am trying to upload a image to Twitter for my reply bot. The current code i have gives no errors but it also doesn't attach the image. I've tried many approaches but i can't get it. Here is my current code.

```
    bot = self.bot
    bot.find_element_by_class_name('Icon--reply').click()
    time.sleep(6) 
    bot.find_element_by_css_selector('input.file-input').send_keys(r'F:\Programming\Python\Tweet Bot\Videos\broom.jpg')
```

Here's a screenshot of the tweet i am using this snippet of code on. https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvoJf.png

Comment: Can you provide your code

Comment: Updated the threads code

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to execute JavaScript on the file input element to reveal it before you can send keys to it.

```
element = bot.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='file']")

bot.execute_script("arguments[0].style.display = 'block';", element)

element.send_keys(filePath)
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, i tried the code above but nothing happens it still just runs with no error or desired result. Here's the code for the function

        bot = self.bot
        bot.find_element_by_class_name('Icon--reply').click()
        time.sleep(6) 
        filePath = r'F:\Programming\Python\Tweet Bot\Videos\broom.jpg'
        element = bot.find_element_by_css_selector('input.file-input')
        bot.execute_script("arguments[0].style.display = 'block';", element)
        time.sleep(1)
        element.send_keys(filePath)

Comment: @BryanReasonableManAdams I believe there was an error in the locator strategy used. I've updated the locator strategy after looking at the HTML on the page link you provided. Give this a try, and let me know if it works.

Comment: Tried it and it still doesn't work i have a hunch that it could be that i have a extension which forces twitter to be the old theme. Its called GoodTwitter. I did this so i could fish out tweet IDs. Here are two screen shots. One of my function and one of the HTML for the button i'm trying to get.

https://i.imgur.com/dpM6kfq.png
https://i.imgur.com/fO9LBVS.png

Comment: The locator strategy matches up with the HTML on the page -- not sure why the issue is happening. The extension shouldn't affect this, but it might. Twitter is pretty advanced, so they probably have a lot of their functionality locked down to limit bot activity.